# Displaying a JScrollPane with data from String

Tags: java

I'm having trouble storing data in the JScrollPane. The line of code that can't compile is 
`scroll.add(flyerList);`
and I don't know why. I'm trying to loop all the data into a single string then put it all in that JScrollPanel.

```
if (event.getSource() == jbtList){
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
        listPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(flyers.size(),1));
        for(int p = 0; p < flyers.size(); p++){
            String flyerList = flyers.get(p) + "\n";
        }

        for(int p = 0; p < flyers.size(); p++){
            scroll.add(flyerList);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,listPanel); 
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant put strings directly into a JScrollPane.
Instead make a JTextArea first

```
if (event.getSource() == jbtList){
    // New textarea
    JTextArea displayStrings = new JTextArea(5, 30);
    // Generate a new JScrollPane and set its viewport to the textarea
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(displayStrings );
    JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
    listPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(flyers.size(),1));
    for(int p = 0; p < flyers.size(); p++){
        String flyerList = flyers.get(p) + "\n";
        displayString.append(flyerList);
    }
```

See: [How to use ScrollPanes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)